# Kubernetes pod status running and going back to completed state

Tags: kubernetes

I’m running my POC java application inside the EKS cluster. Here the steps I followed to move my application into containerized application.

1. Java application source code is checkout into my local workstation.
2. Executed the maven command to generate the package mvn package -DskipTests
3. As usual mvn package command will generate the packages inside the target folder I can see all the dependencies including jar file which has selenium jar to run the test cases.
4. Using docker build command I have created a docker image out of the source code docker build -t myapp .
5. Then I have entered into docker container using below command I can see my test cases are executed successfully without any issue.

dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8u191-jre-alpine

# Workspace
WORKDIR /usr/share/selenium_docker

# ADD jar files and any other dependencies from HOST
ADD target/selenium-docker.jar selenium-docker.jar
ADD target/selenium-docker-tests.jar selenium-docker-tests.jar
ADD target/libs libs

# add TestNG suite files
ADD duck_search_tests.xml duck_search_tests.xml
ADD saucedemo_tests.xml saucedemo_tests.xml

# run tests using provided browser/hub address/test suite module
ENTRYPOINT java -cp selenium-docker.jar:selenium-docker-tests.jar:libs/* -DBROWSER=$BROWSER -DHUB_HOST=$HUB_HOST org.testng.TestNG $MODULE
```

```
docker run -e HUB_HOST=192.168.1.1 -e MODULE=saucedemo_tests.xml -v /c/Users/ /workspace/delete/JavaSeleniumDocker/output:/usr/share/selenium_docker/test-output localhost/myapp

Jul 17, 2023 4:41:44 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Jul 17, 2023 4:41:51 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Logging in to Sauce Demo site...
Logged In!
Home page loaded with page header: Products
Added item to cart
Price of item is: $29.99
Logging in to Sauce Demo site...
Logged In!

===============================================
check_price
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Next i'm moving my docker image into docker hub registry and i'm trying to deploy the image inside the EKS cluster, when i'm doing deployment i can see the pod is up and running and also i run the kubectl logs -f pod command to verify the test case execution i can able to see same like above message like Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0, but problem is pod is restarting every time when the test case execution completed, its again and again pod status is going to CrashLoopBackOff and running .....

here the K8s yaml file

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample-app-deployment-deployment
  namespace: devops-java-selenium
  labels:
    app: sample-app-deployment
    name: sample-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-app-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-app-deployment
        name: sample-app-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: sample-app-deployment
          image: myapp
            env:
             - name: HUB_HOST
               value: "10.1.2.3"
             - name: BROWSER
               value: chrome
             - name: MODULE
               value: 
             - name: selenium_grid_host
               value: "4444"
          volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /usr/share/selenium/test-output
                name: devops-caas-java-selenium-pv
      volumes:
        - name: devops-caas-java-selenium-pv
          hostPath:
             path: /tmp/palani
```

Can you please someone help me on this.

Comment: It looks like you're just running a test job, that mostly only depends on the contents of the image.  Is there a reason it needs to run in a remote clustered environment, or is the existing `docker run` invocation you have enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the nature of a Deployment. When The pod finishes its task, the pod completes. But the Deployment has the purpose to keep up a certain number of pods (replicas) so it will recreate the pod again and again to fullfill its purpose. This is leading to your CrashLoopBackOff. I think maybe you should use a kubernetes job with the restartPolicy: OnFailure for your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for solution i created the POD instead of the deployment object then i added the restart policy never inside the pod spec when the test execution is completed it will not start again.